# Why did the Mu'tazila criticize kalam?

Tags: islamic-philosophy

[Wikipedia - Kalam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalam):

> ʿIlm al-Kalām, usually foreshortened to kalam and sometimes called "Islamic scholastic theology", is an Islamic undertaking born out of the need to establish and defend the tenets of Islamic faith against doubters and detractors.
>
> The contemporary Islamic scholar Nuh Ha Mim Keller holds the view that the criticism of kalam from scholars was specific to the Mu'tazila,

Why did the [Mu'tazila](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu%CA%BFtazila) criticize kalam?

Comment: I'm confused... but are you asking whether Mu'tazila criticize a "science" they maybe practiced the best? Well I understand your quote as that other sects or school of theology criticized the Mu'tazila for using kalam, that would make more sense!

Answer (score -2):

What kalam, the kalam of Allah, if so, They give precedence to logic and reasons over revelation. so they have gone astray with regards to the names and attributes of Allah. They do not believe in Allah's speech.

Comment: You are accusing a group of apostasy without the proper authority. How did you know that they don't believe in Allah's speech? Who gave  you this authority? Do you know that it is haram to accuse other Muslims of apostasy? Do you know only the consensus of scholars may do this?

Comment: @MohammadSakibArifin If anything, you can only ask J.Khan for references; the Mutazilites being considered kuffar by most Asharites and Maturidites is historically clear.